# Trying to figure out the relationship between my tables for SQL

Tags: mysql, relationship

I have two tables

**Exception** which contains
Report Number(Primary Key)
Exception Description

Exception Date Entered

Exception Downtime Hours

**Keyword** which contains

Keyword(Primary Key)

I can't figure out if this is a one to many relationship or a many to many relationship. I know a Exception can have many keywords but can a keyword have many descriptions? I mean a keyword can be used in more then one report but i'm not sure totally. 
I can add more information if needed i'm just really stumped on which it is.
(For this an exception means a machine broke and needs to be fixed and the keyword is what needs to be fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Keyword is a primary key it has to be unique i.e. it's a one-to-many relationship.

So in this design a keyword always refers to the same thing.

If a keyword needs many descriptions, then you could have another descriptions table which has a foreign key to the keywords table...